# Is this generalization bound proof wrong?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, learning-theory

This is an ICML02 paper by Garg, Har-Peled & Roth:
http://sarielhp.org/p/01/bounds/bounds.pdf

The equation after eq. (3) is the well-known symmetrization trick for $\sup_{h\in {\mathcal H}} |E(h)-\hat{E}(h)|$ using a ghost sample, and holds for all $\epsilon>0$. The notation is this: ${\mathcal H}$ is a function class, $E[h]$ is the generalization error of $h$, and $\hat{E}[\cdot]$ is empirical error on a training set. $\epsilon>0$ is a fixed small positive constant.

Now, in the next equation they chose to replace $\epsilon$ by $\rho$ --- but the problem is, this $\rho$ is a function of $h$ and of the training sample $S$, (through the expression of $\epsilon_1(S,\delta)$ on the top of the previous page, which depends on $\nu$, which depends on $h$).
In consequence, in the probability on the r.h.s. now we have an inequality that has $\sup_h$ on its l.h.s. but $\rho=\rho(h,S)$ on its r.h.s.

Is this faulty or am I missing something?

First I thought it's just sloppy notation -- if the $\rho$ did not depend on the training sample then one could replace it with a constant $c$, restrict the function class $\mathcal H$ to have $\rho(h)<c$, and do Structural Risk Minimization over values of $c$. But since $\rho$ also depends on $S$ this is not workable as we cannot have $\mathcal H$ defined to depend on $S$. It seems to me that the only fix would be to restrict $\mathcal H$ to have $\rho(h,S)<c$ *$\forall S$ of size $N$*? -- that would be very strong and impractical. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that their Lemma 3.5 is problematic? The step you mentioned is no more than a direct application of Lemma 3.5.

Comment: Lemma 3.5 is fine -- there h is fixed. It becomes problematic when it is applied in a context where the bound needs to be uniform over all $h$ in $\mathcal H$.

Comment: Suppose the attainment of supremum occurs at $h_{0}\in\mathcal{H}$,$Pr\left[sup_{h\in\mathcal{H}}\left|\widehat{E}(h,S_{1})-\widehat{E}(h,S_{2})\right|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right]=Pr\left[\left|\widehat{E}(h_{0},S_{1})-\widehat{E}(h_{0},S_{2})\right|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right]\leq_{1-2\delta}Pr\left[\left|\widehat{E}(h_0',S'_{1})-\widehat{E}(h_0',S'_{2})\right|>\rho(h_{0})\right]\leq Pr\left[sup_{h'\in\mathcal{H}}\left|\widehat{E}(h',S'_{1})-\widehat{E}(h',S'_{2})\right|>\rho(h_{0})\right]$ is what they argued.

Answer (score 2):

No, they just used sloppy notations. They omitted what we called "attainment argument".

Suppose the attainment of supremum occurs at $h_{0}\in\mathcal{H}$,$$Pr\left[\sup_{h\in\mathcal{H}}\left|\widehat{E}(h,S_{1})-\widehat{E}(h,S_{2})\right|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right]=\operatorname{Pr}\left[\left|\widehat{E}(h_{0},S_{1})-\widehat{E}(h_{0},S_{2})\right|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right]\leq_{1-2\delta}\text{(by Lemma 3.5)}\operatorname{Pr}\left[\left|\widehat{E}(h_0',S'_{1})-\widehat{E}(h_0',S'_{2})\right|>\rho(h_{0})\right]\\\leq \operatorname{Pr}\left[\sup_{h'\in\mathcal{H}}\left|\widehat{E}(h',S'_{1})-\widehat{E}(h',S'_{2})\right|>\rho(h_{0})\right]$$ is what they argued.

Comment: Should that be $\mathcal H'$ in the last line?

Comment: Yes, but we could also regard the projected image as a subspace in $\mathcal{H}$. @axk

Comment: Okay, this makes sense now. But with this argument then in their final bound eq. (2) the $h$ in $\mu_k$ should be the $h_0$ and not the same $h$ as in the empirical average?

Comment: @axk I believe so unless they assumed what you mentioned in OP.

Comment: Still I think they make a hidden assumption here, because $h_0$ depends on $S_1,S_2$ -- so $\rho(h_0)$ is non-random only if they assume so. The last line on the page after eq.(3) only makes sense it $\rho$ is a constant.

Comment: @axk it has been a while since I digged into it, have you asked the authors yet?

Comment: No, I haven't asked the authors.

Comment: @axk since $h$ is eliminated on rhs, the supremum is taken and hence it seems fine even if it depends on $S_i$

Comment: The rhs is $\rho$, which is $\rho=\epsilon/2-\epsilon_1(S_1,\delta)-\epsilon_1(S_2,\delta)$ a random quantity. So they got a random quantity in the last line of page 8, when they should have gotten a probability (a number).